# An exception occurred processing the request: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wrong magic number

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

I have deployed an EAR in **Wildfly-8.2.0-Final** and using **standalone-full-ha.xml** as configuration file. I am getting the below warnings and errors in **server.log** of Wildfly-8.2.0.Final often.

```
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016037: Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource XAResourceRecord < resource:null, txid:< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff84ba6b0e:45f1fb89:56ea3bdb:4c, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff84ba6b0e:45f1fb89:56ea3bdb:4d, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=unknown eis name >, heuristic: TwoPhaseOutcome.FINISH_OK com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord@48a649 >

WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016038: No XAResource to recover < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff84ba6b0e:45f1fb89:56ea3bdb:4c, node_name=1,

branch_uid=0:ffff84ba6b0e:45f1fb89:56ea3bdb:4d, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=unknown eis name >


ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-1) UT005001: An exception occurred processing the request: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wrong magic number

    at io.undertow.server.protocol.ajp.AjpRequestParser.parse(AjpRequestParser.java:185)

    at io.undertow.server.protocol.ajp.AjpReadListener.handleEvent(AjpReadListener.java:160)

    at io.undertow.server.protocol.ajp.AjpOpenListener.handleEvent(AjpOpenListener.java:117)

    at io.undertow.server.protocol.ajp.AjpOpenListener.handleEvent(AjpOpenListener.java:44)

    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92) [xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar:3.3.0.Final]

    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:291) [xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar:3.3.0.Final]

    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:286) [xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar:3.3.0.Final]

    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92) [xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar:3.3.0.Final]

    at org.xnio.nio.NioTcpServerHandle.handleReady(NioTcpServerHandle.java:53) [xnio-nio-3.3.0.Final.jar:3.3.0.Final]

    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539) [xnio-nio-3.3.0.Final.jar:3.3.0.Final]
```

Could anyone please help me out why this error and warnings come and am I missing any in my standalone-full-ha.xml ?

Comment: Hope this helps https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-511

Comment: Try removing your EAR from your application server, clean its temporary folders (in *wildfy_home_folder/standalone/* remove *data* and *tmp*), restart Wildfly and then, after rebuilding your EAR,  try redeploying it again.

Comment: many thanks .. Ravi Ranjan. I also posted in JBoss developer and got a reply that this issue was fixed in Wildfly 10 series. But, I need to use Wildfly 8 and in the JIRA, there is no solution provided.

Comment: @ariberio... this issue occurs after the server is started. EAR is deployed fine irrespective of the number of times I start / stop the server. Issue is this error gets printed and this is something not related to deployment or EAR. Don't know what causes this error.

Comment: @sridhar Where you able to find the solution to this?